# Android C++ Minimalist sample app: "Cannot find module with tag 'gpg-cpp-sdk/android' in import path

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

So, I'm trying to compile the Minimalist sample code from this tutorial. 
https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/gettingStartedAndroid

I have Android SDK and NDK and gpg-cpp sdk installed at C:/Android, and environmental variables set.

so, to my knowledge I've followed the guide to the letter.  But when I run ndk-build inside the jni folder I get the error: Cannot find module with tag 'gpg-cpp-sdk/android' in import path.  Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined?

[image]

"In the guide, the part that mentions setting hte NDK_MODULE_PATH variable, says 
set the variable NDK_MODULE_PATH to point to the directory above the gpp-cpp-sdk directory."

I just realized, the guide says gpp-cpp-sdk while the folder is gpg-cpp-sdk.. 
I just tried changing the name of the folder, but I still got the same error, the error says gpg-cpp-sdk, so I guess it might just be a typo on the guide page.

The Android.mk is the one that came with the project, I didn't make any changes to it.

Comment: Dont post pictures of the code or errors, post it as text in your question.

Comment: how do you copy text from the command line?

Also, here are the Environmental variables set
http://i.imgur.com/1f95D1Y.png     http://i.imgur.com/80t4bw4.png

Comment: If you are having trouble setting ip Android Game Services, use their example from Github: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby-cpp.

Comment: No, I'm trying to compile the example project from Google Play Game Services.  Using the project they provided.

Comment: I did not see that one there. I provided another one. I might be able to test that one later.

Comment: Did you have a chance to look into it for me Jared?

Comment: No, I should be able to tonight. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### I do not use Eclipse for Android Development, so I only went to Step 3.

### Steps from Google docs:

**Source:** https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/gettingStartedAndroid#step_3_run_the_sample

1. Download the Android SDK and the Android NDK and extract them to your machine. In your environment, set SDK_ROOT to the location of your Android SDK folder and NDK_ROOT to the location of your Android NDK folder.
2. Download the C++ sample games. This tutorial refers to the location of the samples on your machine as SAMPLES_DIR.
3. Download the Google Play Game services C++ SDK. Extract the SDK onto your development machine. In your environment, set the variable NDK_MODULE_PATH to point to the directory above the gpp-cpp-sdk directory. You should have the following directory structure:
   NDK_MODULE_PATH/
   gpp-cpp-sdk/

### Here is what I did:

1. git clone "https://github.com/playgameservices/cpp-android-basic-samples.git" "`<some directory>`"
2. In my Terminal: export NDK_MODULE_PATH="`<some directory>`"
3. cd cpp-android-basic-samples/
4. cd samples-android/
5. cd Minimalist/
6. **ndk-build** (this assumes you have the NDK in your path already)

Comment: Still having trouble :/ 

I was running ndk-build from the Minimalist/jni/  instead of jsut Minimalist/ like it says to do in the guide.  

But I think what the problem is, is when I run ndk-build, it says "ignoring unknown import directory: "C:/Android"  which is what I have NDK_MODULE_PATH set to.  

It's a real folder, and it's where the files are, 
http://i.imgur.com/oIx4uPV.png
not sure why it's ignoring it as an import path...  I can't find anything online as to why it is

And when I do: cd %NDK_MODULE_PATH%  it changes to that directory.... so I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: So your `NDK_MODULE_PATH=C:/Android`.

Comment: yes, that is my NDK_MODULE_PATH

maybe that isn't the issue,  when I tried running ndk_build on one of the  android_ndk samples, it still gave that unknown import path error, but was able to compile no problem

Comment: Ah, well if you could compile it, what more do you want? :)

Comment: I've tried changing it to C:/Android  C:/Android/  C:\Android and C:\Android\  but still nothing.  going to try to change the path in the makefile to the absolute path and see if that helps

Comment: no, I could compile a sample from ndk samples no problem,  I'm trying to get a sample from the google samples to compile, and that's where I'm getting the issue.

Comment: I am on a mac, this worked once I exported the variables like I said in my answer. Do you keep getting the same error? It has to be the folder 1 above the google play sdk.

Comment: It is the folder 1 above the google play sdk.
Thank you for taking the time to help me, I'm sorry if I'm being difficult. 

This is the error I'm getting atm 

http://i.imgur.com/sMOEmXT.png

  I'll keep messing around and see if I can figure out the problem.  thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Since you are on windows, how are you setting your variable?

Comment: I set it through System Properties > Environmental Variables.  when changing it to try the other values I set it through the terminal using set NDK_MODULE_PATH="C:/Android"    I just checked to see if editing it through the terminal was changing it and it turns out it wasn't, so I'm going to try the C:/android/ C:/android C:\android C:\android\ setting it through the system properties window   just remembered i was checking through the terminal as I was setting it through the terminal so I'm pretty sure that's not the issue

Comment: What about `C:\Android`?

Comment: well, that was the issue!  now I'm getting an issue about jni/statemanager.h missing.  Talking with you has helped solve my problem.  I think this new issue may be a result of the sample project being a Android10 project, while Android16 is the lowest version I have installed atm.  I changed a variable to bypass the compatibility check.  So now I'm gonna deal with that.  Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. If you have any other questions, just ask! Did my answer help you?

Comment: not really,  well, I guess kind of,  your answer showed to run the ndk-build in the project base folder instead of the /jni folder,  "the google play guide linked said to run it from the /jni folder"  I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer or I would.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Let me know if I help in other NDK problems!

Answer (score -7):

Had to change the NDK_MODULE_PATH to C:/Android instead of C:\Android
and had to change through system properties, editing the variable through terminal using set variable=value, wasn't working, even though checking the path through terminal after changing it through terminal showed that the value was changed.

Comment: Wow. You asked for my help more than once and I helped you figure it out. You mark my answer correct, the you take it away?

Comment: In case you are wondering why this answer suddenly received so many down votes in such a short amount of time: "[Meta Effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292000/user-removed-my-correct-answer-after-i-helped-walked-him-through-his-issue)"